# Wordpress - error 503 - service unavailable

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

Hi my wordpress webpage has been blocked after a day, with a : "error 503 - service unavailable".
after this i have downloaded all plugins and deleted, and then activated one by one.
Now when i press to activate woocomerce plugin it says : error 503 - service unavailable, i have tried to delete and reinstall,remove and download the original plugin again but same problem, i have checked 10+ times for a malware but i couldnt find anything.
Please can someone help me fixing this !

Comment: There could be many possible reasons for this. Your server might be overloaded. Check your server CPU usage. Try to scale the server resources if possible.

Comment: Hello, are you able to check the php error logs or the mysql error logs? otherwise, you can put Wordpress in debug mode and see if the browser displays any error message. Edit wp-config.php and change WP_DEBUG to true, in this way: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please browse the [help for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular [**What topics can I ask about here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This is a site for programming-specific questions, and questions about server issues are not on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Contact your WordPress hosting company because they may be able to pin-point what’s causing the issue.
As a last resort, you can reinstall WordPress with a fresh copy.